# VLC wrapper in monodevelop

Tags: c#-4.0, monodevelop, vlc

I'm programming c# in monodevelop for ubuntu program. When the program is started, it gets run time error. The error message from GDB is here:
Native stacktrace:

```
/usr/bin/mono() [0x80e6431]
/usr/bin/mono() [0x8062b70]
[0xb77b940c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_file_underflow+0x68) [0xb76cb9c8]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_default_uflow+0x19) [0xb7612449]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__uflow+0x90) [0xb7612260]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(getc+0xb2) [0xb7608772]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/liblua5.1.so.0(luaL_loadfile+0xdc) [0xb429fd8c]
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/lua/liblua_plugin.so(+0xa055) [0xb42d8055]
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/lua/liblua_plugin.so(+0xa220) [0xb42d8220]
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/lua/liblua_plugin.so(+0xd689) [0xb42db689]
/usr/lib/vlc/plugins/lua/liblua_plugin.so(+0xa546) [0xb42d8546]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x916a0) [0xb52706a0]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(vlc_module_load+0x573) [0xb5270de3]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(module_need+0x42) [0xb5271302]
/usr/lib/libvlccore.so.5(+0x27716) [0xb5206716]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c) [0xb774fd4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e) [0xb768ddde]
```

Debug info from gdb:

TagLib: MP4: No audio tracks
Unable to attach: program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
Could anyone give a hand about this?
Than you very much